# I have an github account and my user credintials are true. However, I can not login to Travis by using travis login --pro it always give an error

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

travis login --pro

This command not find my account but I am sure that given username and password is true. The reason why I am sure is because I can login my github account with same username and password.

travis report gives this message.

An error occurred running `travis login -e "https://travis-ci.com/"`:
RuntimeError: Not Found
from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/travis-1.10.1.travis.1321.9/lib/travis/tools/github.rb:212:in `rescue in basic_auth' from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/travis-1.10.1.travis.1321.9/lib/travis/tools/github.rb:208:in` basic_auth'
from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/travis-1.10.1.travis.1321.9/lib/travis/tools/github.rb:216:in `login' from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/travis-1.10.1.travis.1321.9/lib/travis/tools/github.rb:81:in` possible_tokens'
from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/travis-1.10.1.travis.1321.9/lib/travis/tools/github.rb:50:in `each_token' from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/travis-1.10.1.travis.1321.9/lib/travis/tools/github.rb:37:in` with_token'
from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/travis-1.10.1.travis.1321.9/lib/travis/cli/login.rb:31:in `login' from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/travis-1.10.1.travis.1321.9/lib/travis/cli/login.rb:50:in` run'
from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/travis-1.10.1.travis.1321.9/lib/travis/cli/command.rb:200:in `execute' from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/travis-1.10.1.travis.1321.9/lib/travis/cli.rb:64:in` run'
from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/travis-1.10.1.travis.1321.9/bin/travis:18:in `<top (required)>' from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/travis:23:in` load'
from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/travis:23:in `'

For issues with the command line tool, please visit https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb/issues.
For Travis CI in general, go to https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues or email support@travis-ci.com.

The versions are

ruby version
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x64-mingw32]

travis version
1.10.0

How can i solve this problem?

Regards,

Answer (score 5):

```
travis login --pro --github-token yourGitHubTokenHere
```

Github token you can find: github.com ->Settings->Developer settings->Personal Access Tokens
or access this link (https://github.com/settings/tokens)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to finally solve it by moving from the gem travis to homebrew travis (not sure if this was the root issue -- but the later helped) + using travis login with the `--github-token` flag.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I followed same way but I ran this command on git bash.

Comment: After additional searching I did come across others with the same issue, and it seems like the `gh` (GitHub) gem might be missing. So others should also try to `gem install gh` or `brew install gh` (if using homebrew).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the [prev answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65775194/14619383), when I reached https://github.com/settings/tokens, I didn't see my github token. Then I re-generated the key and used that. But I forgot to use `--pro` flag and thus faced same issue. After using the `--pro` flag just like given (`travis login --pro --github-token yourGitHubTokenHere`). It has worked fine.

So summary:

- Re-generate your github token if needed or the old one doesn't work
- don't forget to put `--pro` flag in the command.
- makesure to save the token for future use

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, if you are logged on .com, don't forget to add --com on each command, even encrypt, otherwise it defaults to .org